# Loading an SVG into the page using link rel="import"

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am trying to load an SVG file into a HTML page by first including the page in the HTML header:

```
<link rel="import" href="/views/Diagram.svg" />
```

then executing the following script:

```
var link = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"][href="/views/Diagram.svg"]');
var data = link.import;
document.getElementById("svg-diagram").innerHTML = data;
```

Even though the svg is valid (can be displayed), the imported data object contains a parseerror and the svg is not added to the page. I can add the svg using ajax, but since it is to be loaded multiple times, I'd prefer to pre-load it. How can I fix the code?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing

```
document.getElementById("svg-diagram").innerHTML = data;
```

try

```
document.getElementById("svg-diagram").appendChild(data.documentElement);
```

The reason is because data.documentElement is an DOM node object while data is a document object.

Here's what is in the data object

[image: Here's what is in the data object]

Here is what we are going to make use of

[image: Here is what we are going to make use of]

appendChild was used instead of innerHTML because innerHTML expects a string while appendChild can make use of a node object